# Imprimir datos json en etiqueta span

Tags: json, jsonobject, jsonarray, jsonp

soy nuevo en esto del JSON y trata de datos por medio de JS, quisiera su ayuda con lo siguiente:

Trabajo por horas para una empresa que ofrece servicios sistemas de reservas y me pidieron con ayuda de documentación y todo lo demás crear o modificar un script que es "nuevo" para hacer un filtro al estilo de trivago, pero me dieron un código que ya imprimía precio de habitación, nombre de hotel y un botón que genera un enlace externo (esta parte funciona bien), el cual modifique y logre incluir el logo del hotel, pero ahora tengo otra función que debo hacer lo mismo y he intentado de muchas formas algunas de las que estarán incluso comentadas, pero todo me lleva a lo mismo a imprimir el JSON en su totalidad y no solo las partes que necesito del mismo.

Explico un poco más la parte que estoy intentando imprimir es wb.rooms() donde debo tratar de imprimir el nombre de la habitación, la descripción y la o las imágenes que contenga, para poder seguir avanzando con la creación, como mencioné allí es donde está el problema, pego mucho más del código en el que tengo dudas para darles más contexto. De Antemano muchísimas gracias por su ayuda y apoyo prestado.

```
  //Variable action que genera enlace para el boton reservar ahora
                                                var action = "wbs[" + n + "].open({open_on_tab: 1, dfrom: '" + mp_dfrom + "', dto: '" + mp_dto + "', occupancies: '" + guests + "'})";

                                                //imprime los resultados obtenidos de la consulta de disponibilidad
                                                mp_jquery('#mp_results').append('<div class=" col col-sm-12 mp_result mp_result_lcode_' + lcode + '"><h4 style="font-weight:800;">Mejor precio para: </h4><img src="" class="hotel_logo_url" width="80" height="40"/></br> <span class="mp_name"> </span></br><span id="rooms" class="rooms"></span> <span class="mp_value">' + parseFloat(price).toFixed(2) + ' </span><span class="mp_currency"></span> <span class="">Por Persona y por Noche</span></br>  <button class=" btn btn-danger btn-flat" onclick="' + action + '">Revervar Ahora</button></div>');
                                                    

                                                wb.rooms({}, function(data) {
                                                    var roomsR = {
                                                        data
                                                    } 
                                                    var rooms = JSON.stringify(roomsR);
                                                //document.getElementById("rooms").innerHTML=JSON.stringify({ data });
                                                         var valor = '';
                                                          data.rooms.forEach(data => {
                                                            valor += '<tr>'+
                                                             '<td>' + rooms.id + '</td>'+
                                                             '<td>' + rooms.name_es + '</td>'+
                                                             '<td>' + rooms.desc_es + '</td>'+ 
                                                             '<td>' + rooms.images + '</td>'
                                                             ;
                                                          })
                                                          $('#rooms').html(valor);                                              
                                                //document.getElementById("rooms").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
                                                        
                                                //document.getElementById("rooms").innerHTML+="<p>id="+rooms;
                                                //html.innerHTML+="<p>name="+rooms.data.name;                                                                                   
                                                //console.log(JSON.stringify({ roomsR }));

                                                    console.log(roomsR);
                                                })

                                                //recoje todos los valores del resultado de la consulta de disponibilidad
                                                wb.overview({
                                                    'currency': currency
                                                    //'descr_es': descr_es,
                                                }, function(data) {
                                                        //Moneda
                                                    mp_jquery('.mp_result_lcode_' + data['lcode']).find('.mp_currency').text(data['money_sym']);
                                                    //Nnombre del Hotel
                                                    mp_jquery('.mp_result_lcode_' + data['lcode']).find('.mp_name').text(data['name']);
                                                    //Logo del HOtel
                                                     mp_jquery('.mp_result_lcode_' + data['lcode']).find('img').attr('src', data['hotel_logo_url']);
                                            
                                                      

                                                    mp_jquery('.mp_result_lcode_' + data['lcode']).find('.mp_value').text((parseFloat(mp_jquery('.mp_result_lcode_' + data['lcode']).find('.mp_value').text()) * data['currency_conversion']).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: `data` es un objeto o un string? Qué estructura tiene?

Comment: Es un objeto segun las impresiones que me ha dado, de hecho en una me imprimió [objet HTMLCollection]

Comment: Ahorita me iimprime como se ve allí, en la etiqueta me imprime todo undefined pero en el console.log me imprime todo el json.